# Support of multi node type in IBM Cloud Private Cluster

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

IBM Cloud Private supports multi node type, x, p, x in the same cluster, what should we define in the helm deployment in order to make sure a deployment goes to a particular node type?

Answer (score 1):

IBM Could Private supports mixed architectures on the worker nodes.
For example, if you deploy an z application it will only try to run on z nodes.
All the matter nodes should be one architecture, either x or p.

From ICP app center, you can create different charts for different platforms as following:
[app center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oueyC.png)

Answer (score 0):

We found an issue to enable 'nodeSelector' to select different platforms to deploy. This issue was tracked in both ICP and Kubernetes community as below.
ICP issue: https://github.ibm.com/IBMPrivateCloud/roadmap/issues/1737
Kubernetes Chart issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/issues/1899

Answer (score 0):

You can get the node information from Infrastructure-->Node.

Different platforms have different arch images, so we have to use `nodeSelector` to enable the pods to be scheduled to different nodes. We are now trying to enable multiarck docker images here https://github.com/docker-library/official-images , if this finished, then we will do not need `nodeSelector` anymore.

For the usage metric of different nodes in the cluster, you can get resource usage from the dashboard by default. If you install the add-on monitoring framework such as Prometheus etc on ICP, you will get more metrics.